Why do we use both Kullback–Leibler divergence vs FID as metric for evaluating distribution distance?
Kullback–Leibler divergence is used in VAE objective function, while FID measures the quality of images of generative models. But they both measure distribution distance. Why do we have them as different metrics for the same thing?

K-L divergence is not a distance (or a metric, obviously.)  In order for the Fréchet inception distance to be a distance, it seems to me we have to assume that a) the images live in a metric space, b) the feature representations also are in a metric space, c) the transform from image to feature representation preserves relative distance, d) the use of the first two moments of the features (mean, covariance) along with the Frechet distance preserves relative distance in the feature space.  They don't measure the same thing; they give different approximate (rough-cut?) views of the same thing.
